# How to retrieve multiple data in one query Firebase

Tags: ios, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in firebase and nosql. I followed the guide for structuring data and here is what my data look like

```
{"Guardians" : {
      "jojo-pti-gros" : {
          "-KBT2ui6wlC6Fgk1c7Xa" : {
              "creationDate" : "2016-02-26 15:50:56",
              "level" : "2",
              "light" : "2",
              "type" : "Titan"
          }
      }
  },
  "Players" : {
      "jojo-pti-gros" : {
          "console" : "PS4",
          "creationDate" : "2016-02-26 15:50:39",
          "currentGuardian" : "-KBT2ui6wlC6Fgk1c7Xa",
          "email" : "toto@gmail.com",
          "gamertag" : "jojo-pti-gros",
          "guardians" : {
              "-KBT2ui6wlC6Fgk1c7Xa" : "true"
          }
      }
 },
 "Teams" : {
     "-KBhfH9U3CxQPZiCs5ru" : {
         "activity" : "Raid - Normal - Crota's end",
         "creationDate" : "2016-02-29 16:37:14",
         "language" : "Any language",
         "leader" : "jojo-pti-gros",
         "maxPlayers" : "6",
         "mic" : "true",
         "minimumLight" : "55",
         "players" : {
             "jojo-pti-gros" : "true"
         },
         "teamDescription" : "Chaud pour un raid"
     }
 }}
```

When I try to retrieve a team I would like to have a json like this.

```
"-KBhfH9U3CxQPZiCs5ru" =     {
    activity = "Raid - Normal - Crota's end",
    creationDate = "2016-02-29 16:37:14",
    language = "Any language",
    leader = "jojo-pti-gros",
    maxPlayers = 6,
    mic = true,
    minimumLight = 55,
    players = {
        "jojo-pti-gros" = {
            "creationDate" = "2016-02-26 15:50:56",
            "level" = "2",
            "light" = "2",
            "type" = "Titan"
        }
    },
    teamDescription = "Chaud pour un raid"
}
```

But I have this json instead

```
"-KBhfH9U3CxQPZiCs5ru" =     {
    activity = "Raid - Normal - Crota's end",
    creationDate = "2016-02-29 16:37:14",
    language = "Any language",
    leader = "jojo-pti-gros",
    maxPlayers = 6,
    mic = true,
    minimumLight = 55,
    players =         {
        "jojo-pti-gros" = true
    },
    teamDescription = "Chaud pour un raid"
}
```

My code right now

```
    let fb = Firebase(url:myUrl)
    fb.childByAppendingPath("/Teams").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { teams in
        var teamsArray: [Team] = []
        if (teams.value is NSNull) {
            print("no teams found")
        } else {
            print(teams.value)
            for team in teams.value as! NSDictionary {
                let newTeam = Team()
                newTeam.dictionaryToTeam(team.value as! NSDictionary)
                newTeam.id = String(team.key)
                for player in newTeam.playerDictionary as NSDictionary {
                    GuardianAPI.sharedInstance.getGuardianByGamertagAndID(player.key as! String, id: player.value as! String, handler: {newGuardian in
                        newTeam.playerDictionary.setValue(newGuardian, forKey: player.key as! String)
                    })
                }
                teamsArray.append(newTeam)
            }
            handler(true)
        }
    })
```

I don't know how to make a query with juncture like SQL.
Can somebody know how to resolve this ?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I uploaded the json.

Comment: OK, that's somewhat better. Did you already try anything? After reading the [Firebase programming guide for iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/), you should at the very least be able to read the team. Show what you've already tried and we'll have a better idea of where you are stuck and how we can help you.

Comment: Right now, I'm fetching all of my teams then I'm looping on every players and I update every one of them.

Comment: That sounds like code. Add the minimal code to your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of directions to go with this.

One option is to read in your team node, separate out the player refs into perhaps an array and then iterate over the array to get each player ref and load each player with a separate Firebase call

A better option is to store a reference back to the team in each player's node

```
 "Players" : {
      "jojo-pti-gros" : {
         team: "-KBhfH9U3CxQPZiCs5ru"
      }
```

Observe the teams node to load in the team data then then query the players node for all players that have a child: team = "-KBhfH9U3CxQPZiCs5ru"

```
Firebase *playersRef = [myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"Players"];
FQuery *query1 = [playersRef queryOrderedByChild:@"team"];    
FQuery *query2 = [query1 queryEqualToValue:@"-KBhfH9U3CxQPZiCs5ru"];

[query2 observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    NSLog(@"key: %@    %@", snapshot.key, snapshot.value);

}];
```

The result will be a snapshot filled with all of the players that belong to the team.