# Firebase iOS SDK: How to get multiple Data in one query

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, xcode7

I've seen [how to retrieve multiple data in one query firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720686/how-to-retrieve-multiple-data-in-one-query-firebase) so this might be a similar question, but I'm new to Firebase and I don't get it properly.

Here is my situation:

I have a Firebase database like this:
[image: Database structure]

I want to retrieve users who participated in a particular event.
**EDIT**
 
i tried bellow,

```
Firebase* childrens = [server childByAppendingPath:@"Users"];
    Firebase* firebaseUser = [childrens childByAppendingPath:self.myuserid];
    Firebase* firebaseEvent = [firebaseUser childByAppendingPath:@"Events"];
    Firebase* fbuser= [firebaseEvent childByAppendingPath:@"Created"];
FQuery* query1 = [fbuser queryOrderedByChild:@"id"];
    handleFirebase = [query1 observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot){
        NSEnumerator* childrens = snapshot.children;
        [childrens.allObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(FDataSnapshot* rootSnap,NSUInteger rootIndex,BOOL* rootStop){
            NSDictionary* rootData = rootSnap.value;
            NSString* rootKey = rootSnap.key;
            NSLog(@"\nRootKey: %@\nRootData: %@",rootKey,rootData);
        }];
```

here is `NSLog`

```
2016-03-10 15:27:23.399 SquadApp[4425:110128] 
RootKey: olbuzevent1
RootData: {
    createdTime = "2016-03-08T11:53:33Z";
    name = "OLBUZ event 1";
    participents =     {
        "335e63c9-46c6-4ff8-99e7-1537d99731f7" =         {
            id = "335e63c9-46c6-4ff8-99e7-1537d99731f7";
            joinnedTime = 0;
        };
    };
}
2016-03-10 15:27:24.150 SquadApp[4425:110128] 
RootKey: olbuzevent2
RootData: {
    createdTime = "2016-03-08T12:23:28Z";
    name = "OLBUZ event 2";
    participents =     {
        "335e63c9-46c6-4ff8-99e7-1537d99731f7" =         {
            id = "335e63c9-46c6-4ff8-99e7-1537d99731f7";
            joinnedTime = 0;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you please add what you have already tried.

Comment: @JamesFenwick, please check my edit

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

In a NoSQL database you often have to model the data for the way you want to use it in your application. Your current structure is great for showing a list of events that the user organized/participated in. If that is one of your use-cases, that is great.

But if you also have a use-case to show all users that participated in an event, you'll likely have to add a data structure where you track that.

```
event_users
  eventid1
    uid1: 'participant'
    uid2: 'organizer'
    uid3: 'participant'
```

This process is known as denormalization and is covered in one of our (quite old) [blog posts](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) and in the [documentation on structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices). In that last page you should probably also read the [recommendation on nesting](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html#section-nested).