# Receive data many-to-many relation Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I have an extended question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720686/how-to-retrieve-multiple-data-in-one-query-firebase).

What if the player belong to more than one team?

I have this

**json**

```
  "Players" : {
    "-YRHd4IjrjsBXx__B" : {
      "name" : "The best forward",
      "creationDate" : "2016-02-26 15:50:39",
      "teams" : {
         "-KAByPeIz4IjrjsBXx__B" : true,
         "-KEFPuCXcqOah_GJwsMCu" : true,
         "-KEwuQxvGpYTEJ7YQ58-l" : true,
         "-KKF8vPtf8J7cfqFh2PLm" : true
      },
    },
  etc...
  }
```

**players-service.js**

```
getPlayers: function(teamid) {
  var Players = {};
  var teamsIndex = ref.child('teams/' + teamid + '/players/');
  var playersIndex = ref.child('players/');
  teamsIndex.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var playerKey = snapshot.key;
    playersIndex.child(playerKey).on('value', function(playersnap){
      $timeout(function() {
          console.log("key", playerKey);
          players[playerKey] = playersnap.val();
      });
    });
  });
  teamIndex.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
    $timeout(function(snapshot) {
      delete players[snapshot.key()];
    });
  });

  return players;
}
```

But it returns a list of object. I know that I could probably query/change the data structure to/in firebase and return it as a $firebaseArray which I prefer as I use angularfire.

Comment: Do you mean that you want getPlayer to return an array instead of an key value object?

Comment: I'm confused. I'm stuck in between the nosql and SQL worlds. I think i wonder if my solution are the way to go. It could be that need to stick to this solution or denormalize my data more. Haven't diceded yet. A the moment I'm tring to denormalize more. aka put teamid: true in the root of the player node. `"Players" : {
    "-YRHd4IjrjsBXx__B" : {
      "name" : "The best forward",
      "creationDate" : "2016-02-26 15:50:39",
      "-KAByPeIz4IjrjsBXx__B" : true,
      "-KEFPuCXcqOah_GJwsMCu" : true,
      }
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually structure your data depending on how you want to retrieve them.

From my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) you want to get all the players in a team. For this purpose I would use this structure:

```
"Players": {
  "player1": {...},
  "player2": {...},
  "player3": {...}
},
"Teams': {
  "team1": {...},
  "team2": {...}
},
"TeamPlayers" : {
  "team1": {
    "player1": true,
    "player2": true
  },
  "team2": {
    "player1": true,
    "player3": true
  }
}
```

Or using an array

```
"TeamPlayers" : {
  "team1": [
    0: "player1",
    1: "player2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I love you! seriously I do!

Comment: Ahah happy to help! Thanks for upvoting. I've edited with another solution

Comment: This phrase made it to me:  "You usually structure your data depending on how you want to retrieve them."

Comment: how can I show a list of all player1's teams. do I have to do many queries?

Comment: In this case I would use somethings like`ref("TeamPlayers").orderByChild("player1").startAt(true)`. I'm not sure this is the right code but it is the correct approach